# Java Regex - Changing path with an alias

Tags: java, regex

I have a path called $SERVER/public_html/ab1/ab2/.

I want to change it so that instead of $SERVER it just replaces it with my user directory. So I do

```
path = path.replaceFirst("\\$SERVER", System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

but when I run it, it removes my \ in the new string.

```
F:Programming ProjectsJava Project/public_html/ab1/ab2/
```

Comment: You can just do replace('\\','/')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Pattern](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/regex/Pattern.html) has a `String quote(String)` function that will help you for the first string and [Matcher](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/regex/Matcher.html) has `String quoteReplacement(String)` for the second:

```
path = path.replaceFirst(java.util.regex.Pattern.quote("$SERVER"), java.util.regex.Matcher.quoteReplacement(System.getProperty("user.dir")));
```

edit: the reason you have to escape anything is because the second string has the semantics of [Matcher.appendReplacement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29) which treats backslashes and dollars as escape next char and insert captured group resp.

from the doc:

> Note that backslashes () and dollar
>   signs ($) in the replacement string
>   may cause the results to be different
>   than if it were being treated as a
>   literal replacement string. Dollar
>   signs may be treated as references to
>   captured subsequences as described
>   above, and backslashes are used to
>   escape literal characters in the
>   replacement string.

a more obvious solution is (be careful of the needed escaped with that backslash)

```
 path = path.replaceFirst("\\$SERVER", System.getProperty("user.dir").replaceAll("\\\\","\\\\\\\\"));
```

Comment: Very interesting solution. I like it. +1

Comment: Thanks this work but replaceFirst is basic calling     Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(str).replaceFirst(repl)

Comment: +1 - This is the correct explanation and the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yea you are completly right. I am trying to figure out why it is happening so.

But at the moment the only think I can suggest is to go with such a solution.

```
public class RegExTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String path = "$SERVER/public_html/ab1/ab2";
        System.out.println("path before="+path);
        String user = System.getProperty("user.dir");       
        System.out.println("user="+user);
        System.out.println("replaceFirst using user="+path.replaceFirst("\\$SERVER", user));
        path = path.replaceFirst("\\$SERVER", "");
        path = user +path;
        System.out.println("path after="+path);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: *..Why it does that?*

From what I see in the code of the method line 701 to 708 they must do it. They just skip them. As to the reason why they do it, I still am not sure.

**EDIT2:** 
OK reading the doc for the method answers it all. They do it so they can interpret accordingly special characters. Thus when reading the replacement they spot a slash the algorithm assumes it can be a part of special character and in result skips it.

```
            if (nextChar == '\\') {
                cursor++;
                nextChar = replacement.charAt(cursor);
                result.append(nextChar);
                cursor++;
            } else if (nextChar == '$') {
                // Skip past $
                cursor++;
```

Comment: Thanks I figured out another way to do it, I'm just little curious on why it's doing that in the first place.

Comment: @K.T check the edit. There is a code snippet from the method which I would say is responsible for it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so in Windows the default slashes look like so '\' whereas on *nix the slashes look like so '/' .  The simplest way to get through this problem is to invoke the `replace` function with the following parameters `'\\'` and `'/'` .  That way you path will have its slashes all facing the same way.

Comment: Yes ... this will work, but it is not a general solution.  Suppose for instance that he didn't want to change \ to / ... or that he wanted to change / to \.  FWIW, the `File(String)` constructor is happy with mixed \ and / in raw pathnames ... it normalizes to the default file separator.

Comment: Some command line functions will fail if the slash is wrong.  The general solution I've seen is to check the operating system and swap as needed